# how to maintain the state for each radio button in a table view - react

Tags: reactjs

I am having the below html table view.
[image]
Using React, I am trying to change the `checked` value when a user change any radio button in a row.

I am trying this onchange function but its not working

```
changeStatus(e)
{
  if(e.target.value === 'on')
  {
    e.target.checked = true
  }
  else
  {
    e.target.checked = false
  }
  console.log(e.target.value + e.target.checked)
}
```

Render function

```
    {records.length>0 && records.map((row,i) => (
              // this.state.radio_val[row.id] = row.status;
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{i+1}</td>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>          
                  <div className="form-check form-switch">
                  <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  onChange={this.changeStatus.bind(this)} />
                  {/* <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label> */}
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <Link to={"/brand/"+row.slug}>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-info active"> <i className="fas fa-edit"></i > Edit</button>
              </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
   ))}
```

Please guide me to maintain the state for the rows of radio buttons. I want to change the radio button state while changing the value.

Comment: keep a local state for tracking the radio button status based on the row id.

Comment: if there is one radio button means, i can able to have the state with one name. but here I am having 'N' times of radio buttons how to define the state for this and how to attach to the element

Comment: I have created a codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sound-j0zbt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the state of the checkboxes in an array.

Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-currying-0e628?file=/src/App.js) using class-based component

```
  state = {
    checkboxes: Array(10).fill(false)
  };

  updateCheckbox(selectedIndex, { target: { checked } }) {
    this.setState(({ checkboxes }) => ({
      checkboxes: checkboxes.map((prev, index) =>
        index === selectedIndex ? checked : prev
      )
    }));
  }
```

and the JSX

```
{this.state.checkboxes.map((checked, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={this.updateCheckbox.bind(this, index)}
          />
))}
```

When the checkbox changes, the corresponding element is updated based on the index. You can use id instead of index.

Comment: how to show the already checked data, given sample is working for current changed. I want to show the already filled state also.

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi Just modify the initial state based on the existing data instead of using an array of false elements